# How to segment objects in an image?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that contains objects. I was able to identify and apply watershed segmentation to separate the objects, but I didn't get the desired results. The white images are objects and I am trying to extract each one separately. Kindly need your help.

```
for color in colour[1:]:
img_new_copy = copy.copy(img_rgb)

img_mask = np.zeros(markers.shape)
img_mask[markers==color] += 255
img_mask = cv2.dilate(img_mask,kernel,iterations=2)
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(img_mask > 0))
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_mask.astype(np.uint8), 1, 2)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
img_new_copy[img_mask==0] *= 0
image_object = img_new_copy[x:x+w,y:y+h,:]
if w > 200 or h > 200:
    continue
else:
    grain = rotate_bound(image_object, cv2.fitEllipse(coords)[-1]-180)
```

This is the image showing the objects separated from background and the markers from the watershed image:

[image]

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: The white ones are the objects .I need to extract each one of them

Comment: You should better define what is the desired result. In the example you attach there are some noise like areas and some border effects. If you want to keep these then the result looks somewhat alright, in case you do not want these included you should investigate some morphological operation in your pipeline.

Comment: I am trying to separate each object and store it in a file.If you look at the first image I have separated them from background.Now how do I extract them individually